# javascript array loop for reassigning element ID's

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, datepicker

I am creating a form with input elements that are leveraging a jquery datepicker.  Here is an example of what my HTML looks like for these inputs:

```
<td style="width:15%"><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="Tb3fromRow10"/></td>
<td style="width:15%"><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="Tb3toRow10"/></td>
```

I'm running into an issue where I need the date format to be mm/dd/yyyy, but the database only accepts formats in yyyy-mm-dd.  As a result, I'm trying to hack it by having it show up as mm/dd/yyyy on the form, but have an eventlistener onSubmit that changes all the date formats to yyyy-mm-dd so that the database can record it.  To do this, I am trying to write a loop that creates an array based on getElementsByName (since I named all of these elements "datepicker"), changes all of their formats, and then reassigns all of their ID's.  I think I've done the first two steps, but am stuck on the last step of reassigning ID's:

```
var myArray = document.getElementsByName('datepicker[]');
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var sep = myArray.split('/');
    var newDate = sep[2]+'-'+sep[0]+'-'+sep[1];
}
**document.getElementsByName('datepicker[]').value = newDate;**
```

I know the last line is incorrect, can someone help me with reassigning all of the date elements to their appropriate ID's?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of datepicker and do you validate the form fields? client as server side?

Comment: why don't you use the backend to deal with the peculiarities of your DB? since you already use PHP: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $str ));`

Answer (score 1):

You are not reassigning IDs. But you are not using the myArray correctly. Here is what you need to change assuming  `name="datepicker[]"` and not `name="datepicker"` like in the HTML part of your example:

```
var myArray = document.getElementsByName('datepicker[]'); // or ("datepicker") depending on their name
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var sep = myArray[i].split('/');
  var newDate = sep[2]+'-'+sep[0]+'-'+sep[1];
  myArray[i].value = newDate;
}
```

anyway, why not validate and reformat on the server before storing?

Comment: oops so my html is actually name="datepicker", so should my first line be var myArray = document.getElementsByName("datepicker"); then?  Also I'm working out of ServiceNow and I've tried everything to reformat the date on their system...not sure if this is a bug or what.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the name the fields have. Be it datepicker or datepicker[]

Comment: If the datepicker rewrites the HTML then it will not necessarily work the way you expect